# require all namespaces by prefix

Tags: dependency-injection, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have an application that can be extended with `defmethod` calls. The application should be extended in runtime by adding new namespaces to the classpath that contain additional `defmethod` calls.

I am looking for a dependency injection solution. The question is: how will my application know what namespaces it should `require` so that the `defmethod` calls can take effect?

1. One solution is to have a central configuration file that contains the names of the namespaces that can be required. A drawback is that I need to edit the configurations by hand when I want to enable a plugin.
2. An other way is to somehow dynamically scan the classpath for additional namespaces and require them based on a predicate (for example a namespce name prefix).

I found only these two solutions but I wonder what other ways may be around to do runtime dependency injection in Clojure. And what libraries are commonly used for this purpose?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have an application that can be extended with defmethod calls"? You have a `defmulti` defined that users can create methods for?

Comment: Yes, the application has some multimethods in its core pipeline and the users should extend the functionality with defmethod calls.

Comment: Why does your application need to require namespaces? The users implementing a method should be sufficient unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: I guess this is mostly a question about how to load user-supplied code (plugins), whatever that code does.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 dependency injection frameworks commonly used in Clojure land:

- [Component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component)
- [Mount](https://github.com/tolitius/mount)
- [Integrant](https://github.com/weavejester/integrant)

Of these, Integrant will probably fit your way of thinking best. However, in the past I've thought that I had the problem you are describing, and gone with the scan for namespaces that need to be required approach. But in the fullness of time I realised that I was structuring by code in a sub-optimal way, and thinking about it differently made the code easier to follow and fixed this backwards dependency problem at the same time. Your situation may well be different. The searching for namespaces to load does work though ;)